# Trying to get many SQL results into a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have a SQL statement that generates many separate results. I need to see how to make it a single resultset.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 DATETIME) 
DECLARE @StartDT DATETIME 

SET @StartDT =  '20160101'

WHILE @StartDT < '20200201' 
BEGIN   
    SELECT 
        @StartDT AS [Month], 
        SUM([OrderTotal]) AS [Months Order Total]   
    FROM 
        [dbo].[tb_Order]   
    WHERE
        ApplicationId = '24b48d78-1fb8-4842-af6d-11c58e940700' 
        AND OrderStatusId IN (10, 20, 30)
        AND OrderDate BETWEEN @StartDT AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDT)

    --SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table WHERE Col2 >= @StartDT AND Col2 < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT)   SET @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT)
END
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to learn about `GROUP BY`? Your intention seems to be to get the sum of the orders' values per month in the given time period. I don't think you need any procedural code for that at all. Try:

```
SELECT concat(year(orderdate),
              month(orderdate),
              '01') month,
       sum(ordertotal) ordertotal
       FROM dbo.tb_order
       WHERE applicationid = '24b48d78-1fb8-4842-af6d-11c58e940700'
             AND orderstatusid IN (10,
                                   20,
                                   30)
             AND orderdate >= '20160101'
             AND orderdate < '20200301'
       GROUP BY year(orderdate),
                month(orderdate)
       ORDER BY year(orderdate),
                month(orderdate);
```

Also don't use `BETWEEN` on `datetime`s like you did. You might lose data as anything after 00:00 o'clock of the second operand isn't included anymore. Use `<` and the next day at 00:00 as boundary.

Comment: thanks, for the tip, I normally never use between. Now I'll remember your notes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a temp table at the beggining of your script and doing an INSERT into that in your WHILE loop and then SELECTing from that at then end

```
CREATE TABLE #Month
(
    Month AS DATETIME,
    MonthsOrderTotal AS DECIMAL (8,2) -- or whatever your data type should be
)

DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 DATETIME)
DECLARE @StartDT DATETIME SET @StartDT =  '20160101'

WHILE @StartDT < '20200201' BEGIN   

    INSERT INTO #Month
    SELECT  @StartDT as [Month],
            sum ([OrderTotal]) as [Months Order Total]
    FROM    [dbo].[tb_Order]
    WHERE   ApplicationId = '24b48d78-1fb8-4842-af6d-11c58e940700' AND
            OrderStatusId in (10,20,30) AND
            orderdate between @StartDT AND
            DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT)

    SET @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT)
END

SELECT  Month,
        MonthsOrderTotal
FROM    #Month

DROP TABLE #Month
```